# How can I motivate a cat to go outside their hideout?

Tags: cats

I've checked in at some hotel late at night, some street or neighbor cat entered my room as I was ventilating the room, and decided to stay under the bedframe near the wall. I would like the cat to leave as I need to sleep and don't want the cat to be in the room during my sleep.

The cat is between the bedframe and the wall, at the end of the "tunnel":

[image]

[image: tunnel entrance]

The only way out is to via where I took the picture. I can't move the bedframe as it is attached to the wall. I don't have pet food or toy with me. I'd prefer not to have to bang on the wall to avoid pissing off the neighbors (it's 5am). How can I motivate the cat to go out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like quite the obstacle. I found a really good article that helps address this.

Food or treats are best it seems. I would discourage using loud noises or quick movements. That could force the shy cat to stay put.

Check out this article:
https://www.cuteness.com/article/lure-cat-out-hiding

It has some other great suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, great link!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if you don't mind :) I'd love if others with similar issues would find this helpful as well!